# Check if node update is published

Tags: workflows

I've a content type with a workflow.
I have to notify users when the published version of the node is update.

Have I to check which transition is used? How?

I'm using an hook_node_presave.

[EDIT]
It seems that check if it's the default revision could be right:

```
 $entity->isDefaultRevision();
```

From draft to draft is false.
From draft to published is true.
From published to published is true.

Could be the right way?

Comment: Don’t you want hook_ node_update?

Comment: I could change to node_update, but how should I access to transition information?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: However: this method returns true also with transition from "published" to "archived". The way is how to check which transition is performed

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider using the [Content moderation notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_moderation_notifications) module:

> Allows notifications to be sent to all users of a particular role, or to the content's author when a piece of content is transitioned from one state to another via core's content_moderation module.

I've used it with good results in several sites.

Comment: I see it, but I've to notify all users that have edited the node (with a loop on all the revisions). I could use that module with an hook..

Comment: But the plumbing is there, you might be able to hook in and alter the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the Moderation state of node in the hook_node_presave(). like below:

```
$node->get('moderation_state')->getString()
```

It will give you the string like publish or unpublish.